# Debug is not working in Eclipse for TCl, Run do works

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tcl

I have this main.tcl

```html
source scripts/VeriwaveProc.tcl
source scripts/ConfigurationTableReader.tcl


set i 0
set arg_to_pass_to_object ""

try {
 Veriwave oVeriwave -port1 {eth} -port2 {wlan} -config_file {SetupConfigs\Coex}
} on error {result options} {
     puts "$result"
}
```

and also VeriwaveProc.tcl

```html
package require itcl
namespace import itcl::*

#Local class just for initializing and Analyse results,
itcl::class Veriwave {

 #Varliable declartions:
    public variable ip                  ""
 public variable managementIP       ""     
 public variable user         ""
 public variable password        ""
 public variable hostConnected       ""
 public variable hostname        ""
 public variable wlanHome        ""               
 public variable config_file        ""   ;#the xml config filename
 public variable config_file_extension     ""   ;# .wml // .wrl
 public variable test_type        ""   ;# .wml // .wrl
 public variable use_sniffer        "0"  ;#false= 0 or true=1
 public variable ConfigArr_BasicParam       ""   ;#a dict {param value param v..} type.
 public variable ConfigMtx_ClientsParam           ;#an array of dict (matrix) {param value #param v..} type. For each client allocate1 entry in array
 public variable excelEnv         ;#Object with type :ConfigurationTableReader  and name:excelEnv
 
 # All port corresponding to specific Veriwave setup eth / wlan / none / radar
        public variable port1 ""
        public variable port2 ""     
        public variable port3 ""       
        public variable port4 ""
        public variable port5 ""
        public variable port6 ""
        public variable port7 ""
        public variable port8 ""
        public variable port9 ""

    constructor {args} {    
         eval configure $args    
   
  # set ConfigMtx_ClientsParam to an array
  array set ConfigMtx_ClientsParam {}
     
  ConfigurationTableReader "excelEnv" \
          -XLS_file_path "${config_file}.xls" \
          -CSV_file_path "${config_file}.csv"
   
    }
    destructor { clear    }
 
    #Methods declarations:
 method Run_test    {settings}         ;#testname configKey
 method init_Veriwave   {settings}
 method Read_map_Excels   {}
 method Change_wml_BasicParam  {}
 method Change_wml_ClientsParam  {}
 method Cleanup    {}
 

}


###################### Procedure Name : Run_test ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::Run_test {setting} {

 init_Veriwave $setting 
 Read_map_Excels
 
}


###################### Procedure Name : init_Veriwave ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::init_Veriwave {settings} {


 
}



###################### Procedure Name : Read_map_Excels ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::Read_map_Excels {} {

 
}


###################### Procedure Name : Change_wml_BasicParam ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::Change_wml_BasicParam {} {
 
}


###################### Procedure Name : Change_wml_ClientsParam ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::Change_wml_ClientsParam {} {
 
}


###################### Procedure Name : Cleanup ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
body Veriwave::Cleanup {} {
 
}


###################### Procedure Name : Convert_sniffer_output_to_pcap ################################################################
#
# Description: 
#
# Arguments:    
#
# Return Value : 
#         
#
# Author/date : Sion/24.03.2014
###############################################################################
proc Convert_sniffer_output_to_pcap {src_file_path src_file_name dst_file_path dst_file_name} {
 
}
```

I get the following error :

```
Execution error 206: bad level "-1"
    while executing
"DbgNub_infoCmd level -1"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd DbgNub_infoCmd $args"
    invoked from within
"::info level -1"
    invoked from within
"info level -1"
    while constructing object "::oVeriwave" in ::Veriwave::constructor (body line 4)
    invoked from within
"Veriwave oVeriwave -port1 {eth} -port2 {wlan} -config_file {SetupConfigs\Coex}"

Stack trace:
    #0 file:/C:/AutomationHome/Veriwave/main.tcl [10]
```

Have no idea Y . Tnx

Comment: Looking at the trace, it looks like something's overridden the standard implementation of the `info` and `uplevel` commands…

Comment: What is it ? all the code is presented here, I removed the :         constructor {args} {    
         eval configure $args 
and inserted the     constructor {} {     instead and it works but still not able to do configure to a variable. tnx